# How to get the host OSGI console for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi

I made an eclipse plugin.  Testing it via "Run As -> Eclipse Application" works great.  It always comes up with a console for me and I can interact with the OSGI shell from the eclipse that launched it.  Now I want to try a test deploy where I put my plugin and its dependencies into the dropins folder of an eclipse distro.  Once the application launches, how can I bring up the OSGI console so that I can interact with my plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add the `-console` option to the launch arguments.  Eg, something like this:

```
eclipse -console
```

Note that if `-console` is added to eclipse.ini, then it must appear before `-vmargs`.

[See here for more information on Eclipse command line arguments.](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html)

Comment: Thanks! I had put -console in my eclipse.ini a little too quickly, I was putting it in after some -vm arguments.  It is worth noting that -console option brings up the console in the terminal window from which you launch, so be sure to launch from a terminal window.

Comment: That's right.  Should have mentioned that -console must come before -vmargs.  Thanks for pointing that out.